# Get Active Albums in Facebook Using FQL Query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm using the Below Query to retrieve the Album Names and album id,

```
    SELECT aid,name FROM album WHERE owner = me()
```

But in these fql query it retrieve all albums Name. But some of the albums doesn't have photos and also it retrieve the deleted albums. I dont want the ablum doesn't have photos and inactive.

So Please guide me how to retrieve in fql Query ?

Comment: For only getting albums that actually contain photos, add `AND photo_count > 0` to the where clause. As for “inactive”, I don’t know what you actually mean by that.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your reply. . It's worked for me. . Post it as an answer. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For only getting albums that actually contain photos, add `AND photo_count > 0` to the WHERE clause.